# Check what values from a pandas dataframe are not in a SQL batabase

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-server, pandas

I want to check what values from a pandas dataframe are not in a SQL database. So basically a left join(left being pandas df) where the right(SQL DB) key is NULL.

The DB is quite big, about 5 million entries, but i'm only interested in the primary key.

Pandas dataframe(50k rows) is much smaller than the SQL DB(5M), so i'd
rather move data to the batabase that bring all of it

I've thought about creating a temporary table in SQL and making a LEFT JOIN, but it might be possible to do it with just a query

pandas dataframe:

```
    index   
    0        
    1  
    2  
    3  
    4
```

sql database:

```
    index(primary key)     
    1        
    2        
    3
```

`result: 0, 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder what's "batabase"... Google didn't help me on that :-)

However, if I understand that correctly, I think you should create a one-column temporary table in SQL server out of the dataframe (as you suggested yourself) and then of course it would be easy to find it like that:

```
SELECT P.Index 
FROM PandasTable as P 
WHERE P.Index NOT IN 
    (SELECT B.Index FROM BatabaseTable)
```

Should be pretty fast with indexed primary keys.

Comment: ooops :)  thanks! I thought there would be a way of doing it without creating a table